# The mmer function of sommer using unstructured variance: singularity arriving quickly and negative variances after

Tags: r, mixed-models, variance

So I am analyzing a multi-site trial of rice breeding lines at 4 environments. The simplified data is here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jilVXX8JMkZCDVtIRmrwzB55kgR2GtYB/view?usp=sharing

And I am runnning a simple model with unstructured variance on sommer. I have done it on lme4 and nlme, but let's just say I want to stick with sommer. The model is:

```
m3 <- mmer(RDM ~ ENV ,
              random=~ vsr(usr(ENV),GEN),
              rcov=~ units,
              data=d)
```

Pretty simple, no? However, very quickly I get the error:

```
System is singular (V). Stopping the job. Try a bigger number of tolparinv.
```

So, ok, I try a bigger tolparinv number (as I can't make a simpler model). But the smallest number that makes the function work is 1000. So, my question is: **what are the implications of this?**

Moreover, let's say that it is ok to run the model like that. And now what happens is that many of my variance components are negative. Which doesn't make much sense.

Could somebody please shed some light on this? So, the concrete questions are:

- Why is singularity arriving so quickly?
- What happens if I increase so much tolparinv?
- Is that why my variance is negative?
- And most importantly: is this fixable? How?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

The unstructured models tend to have convergence issues and singularities due to the many covariance parameters, and the high likelihood of getting non-full-rank covariance matrices during the REML process. You may want to try reduced-rank factor analytic models to guarantee the convergence and increase speed. The regular US model looks like this

```
library(sommer)
data(DT_example)
DT <- DT_example
A <- A_example
head(DT)
DT=DT[with(DT, order(Env)), ]
ans2us <- mmec(Yield~Env,
             random= ~ vsc(usc(Env),isc(Name)),
             rcov= ~ vsc(dsc(Env),isc(units)),
             data=DT)
plot(ans2us$llik[1,])
summary(ans2us)$varcomp
pp <- predict(ans2us, D="Name")
pp$pvals
```

The FA implementation looks like this

```
# less accurate but is guaranteed to converge
M <- with(DT, rrc(Env, Name, Yield, nPC=2))
ans2fa <- mmec(Yield~Env,
              random= ~ vsc(usc( M ),isc(Name)),
              rcov= ~ vsc(dsc(Env),isc(units)),
              nIters = 100,
              data=DT)
summary(ans2fa)$varcomp
plot(ans2fa$llik[1,])
ppfa <- predict(ans2fa, D="Name")

Lam <- with(DT, rrc(Env, Name, Yield, nPC=2, returnLam = TRUE))$Lam
scores <- ans2fa$uList[[1]]
BLUP <- scores %*% t(Lam) # environment specific predictions

# highly correlated predictions
plot(pp$pvals$predicted.value, ppfa$pvals$predicted.value)
```

Cheers